# Installation instructions of PhoneGap-2.1.0 in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cordova

I need to use PhoneGap-**2.1.0** but I can only find installation instructions for the PhoneGap/Cordova-**2.5.0**.

The instructions I found are: [Installation of PhoneGap-2.5.0](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.5.0/guide_getting-started_ios_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20iOS)

I tried to follow them for the 2.1.0 version but it refers to a "bin" folder which doesnt exist in the 2.1.0 version.

Can someone please give me the complete instructions to create an iOS project with phonegap-**2.1.0** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.1.0/guide_getting-started_ios_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20iOS) it is . For any version of PhoneGap, just change the version in the URL!

Comment: Thank you , exactly what i was looking for! Smart move to change the URL accordingly :D

Answer (score 0):

The post is for all version after 2.1
for now i am focusing on 2.7

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.7.0/guide_getting-started_ios_index.md.html

These instructions are pretty clear, even if the directory tree you get after extracting the zip file is not exactly the one they show.

After installing all the requirements:

1. extract the content of phonegap-2.7.0.zip wherever you want
2. go to lib/ios/bin and run the create command with the suggested parameters.
3. open the finder and go to the directory you used as first parameter
4. doubleclick the file with extension xcodeproj to open XCode and the project will be automatically created

Comment: he was asking about phonegap 2.1, and the post is a year old

Comment: The post is for all version after 2.1. People still can get advantage therefore i posted :)